# Spring JMS MQListener not consuming messages automatically

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Spring boot JMS application used for consuming and sending messages to IBM mQ. We have around 10 IBM MQ configured for this application and I'm using SimpleMessageListenerContainer with CachingConnectionFactory to avoid multiple connection start/close for the application. Message sending is happening properly here, wherein we are seeing issues with the consumption. Messages are not getting consumed by the application automatically. We have to do a application restart each time. After some research, i got to see from some blogs that Caching is not a good option for Message Consumption if that queue is idle for long time.

In my scenario, this is true since the message flow to this particular queue is in every 24 hrs. So my application is keeping the session open for long time and making the connection from the cache. If no messages are coming to the queue, firewall time out will happen. Since the broker doesnt know about that it will reuse the same connection.

So i guess I need to remove the cachedconnectionfactory and use the SimpleMessageListenerContainer directly. Any suggestions on this ? Thank you.

Comment: IBM MQ client/queue manager by default send heartbeat messages when a channel is idle.  The `HBINT` of the `SVRCONN` channel will define the interval in seconds at which a heart beat message is sent if no other traffic has passed over the channel.  The client  should always initiate the HB and the queue manager will respond.  If the queue manager does not get a HB request in HBINT+5 it will initiate a HB to the client and expect a response.

Comment: The timeout is based upon 2*HBINT for HBINT's of less than 60 seconds and
HBINT + 60 for HBINT's of over 60 seconds. The default HBINT on a SVRCONN is 300 so the TIMEOUT of a channel at the MQ level is 360 seconds.  This could happen on either the client or server side.  Note that at clients v6 or older HB messages are only sent when the client is in a GET with WAIT operation, not at other times.  What version of MQ client jar files are using with spring?  What is the timeout value for the firewall?